# Stored Proc no error but does not insert data in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have Postgres as my database. I have created a function that inserts data into the postgres database (code below). MIt does not return any error but it also does not insert anything to my database. What should I change in here?

I have a model class (which is in a separate file). To use this model class (code below), I import it in my app.py.

**model.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import os


class DBconn:
    def __init__(self):
        engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:admin@127.0.0.1:5432/backend', echo=False)
        self.conn = engine.connect()
        self.trans = self.conn.begin()

    def getcursor(self):
        cursor = self.conn.connection.cursor()
        return cursor

    def dbcommit(self):
        self.trans.commit()

    def dbexecute(self, query, parameters):
        self.conn.execute(self, query, parameters)
```

This is my postgres function:

**function**

```
create or replace function newcounselor(par_username text, par_password text, par_firstname  text, par_middleinitial text, par_lastname text, par_contact text, par_code text, par_affiliation text, par_city text, par_done boolean) returns text as
  $$
    declare
      loc_code text;
      loc_res text;
    begin
       select into loc_code code from counselors where code = par_code ;
       if loc_code isnull then

         insert into counselors (firstname, middleinitial, lastname, contact, code, affiliation, city, done) values (par_firstname, par_middleinitial, par_lastname, par_contact, par_code, par_affiliation, par_city, par_done);
         insert into users (username, password, code) values (par_username, par_password, par_code);
         loc_res = 'OK';

       else
         loc_res = 'ID EXISTED';
       end if;
       return loc_res;
    end;
  $$
   language 'plpgsql';
```

And in my **app.py** I execute that function using this python function:

```
def insert(sp, params, commit=True):
    try:
        dbo = DBconn()
        cursor = dbo.getcursor()
        cursor.callproc(sp, params)
        cursor.callproc(dbo.dbexecute())

        if commit:
            dbo.dbcommit()
            return
        else:
            return 'Error inserting data'
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Then, to insert data using the python function, i use it this way (the username, password, etc are from my variables.. i already tested this variables and it contains my user's inputs...:

```
insert("newcounselor", (username, password, firstname, middleinitial, 
lastname, contact, code, affiliation, city))
flash('You are now registered', 'success')
redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: Does this function work if you call it manually via psql (or any other postgresql client)?

Comment: Yes. I used pgadmin it runs.. that's why I am not sure why it is behaving like this. :(